# How to hide logic from your code and show only public functions with documentation?

Tags: php, oop

When I control click into a php function, it drives me to its definition and I can see the documentation and the function declaration, but no logic inside. The brackets are empty. I would like to know how if its posible to do something similar in my code and how it can be done.

What i dont understand is that there is no code inside this class file, and no include statements, but the methods works when I use them in my code. And when I click onto these methods I'm linked to this file. How can I do something similar or how does it works??
This is an exmample of what I would like to do:

```
/**
 * Retrieve item from the server
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php
 * @param key string <p>
 * The key or array of keys to fetch.
 * </p>
 * @param flags int[optional] <p>
 * If present, flags fetched along with the values will be written to this parameter. These
 * flags are the same as the ones given to for example Memcache::set.
 * The lowest byte of the int is reserved for pecl/memcache internal usage (e.g. to indicate
 * compression and serialization status).
 * </p>
 * @return string the string associated with the key or
 * an array of found key-value pairs when key is an array.
 * Returns false on failure, key is not found or
 * key is an empty array.
 */
public function get ($key, &$flags = null) {}

/**
 * Delete item from the server
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.delete.php
 * @param key string <p>
 * The key associated with the item to delete.
 * </p>
 * @param timeout int[optional] <p>
 * This deprecated parameter is not supported, and defaults to 0 seconds.
 * Do not use this parameter.
 * </p>
 * @return bool Returns true on success or false on failure.
 */
public function delete ($key, $timeout = null) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are stubs for documentation. There is no technique of *hiding* the code here.

The actual code isn't PHP and can be found for example here https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard

or can be downloaded at the php.net website.

Comment: can you show me an example link of documentation to do this?

Comment: Do do what exactly? Generate stub files?  There are some tools that can do that for you. Look for PHP stub file generators. For example:  https://packagist.org/packages/racztiborzoltan/ide-stub-generator

Comment: what i dont understand is that there is no code inside this class file I posted, and no include statements, but the methods works when I use them in my code. And when I click into these methods I'm linked to this file. How can I do something similar or how does it works??

Comment: Read my answer again. I know there is no code in the file, it is a STUB file for documentation purposes only.  There IS NO PHP code. The actual PHP functions are not made in PHP.  The linking to stub files is only for documentation. PHP is written in C and C++. They are loaded as an IDE plugin, the reason why your IDE ctrl-click works.